Troubleshooting Connection Refused Errors Across Nodes in Cluster Setup
I have three nodes bound to a virtual IP, with each node connecting using port 2892. I initiate connections from node1 to node2 and from node2 to node3, both using port 2892. Below are the relevant network connections:
(I am representing nodes as x,y,z and its virtual Ip as x-vip,y-vip, z-vip)
Output from node1 (x):
tcp6       0      0 x-vip:2892      :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 x-vip:2892      y:58730                 ESTABLISHED
Output from node2 (y):
tcp6       0      0 y-vip:2892     :::*                    LISTEN  
tcp6       0      0 y-vip:2892     z:40464                 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 y:58730        x-vip:2892              ESTABLISHED
Output from node3 (z):
tcp6       0      0 z-vip:2892     :::*                    LISTEN   
tcp6       0      0 z:40464        y-vip:2892              ESTABLISHED
I attempted to establish connections to node1 (x) from node3 (z) and node2 (y) using various combinations of machine IP addresses and virtual IPs. However, I encountered 'Connection refused' errors in all cases. Below are the commands I used on each node:
Commands executed on node1 (x):
Attempted connections to port 2892 on node2 (y) and node3 (z) using both their machine IP addresses and virtual IPs. However, all attempts resulted in 'Connection refused' errors while using machine IP addresses to connect.
nc -vz z 2892
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
nc -vz y 2892
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
Commands executed on node2 (y):
Tried connecting to node1 (x) and node3 (z) using their machine IP addresses and virtual IPs. In both cases, I received 'Connection refused' errors while connecting using machine IP addresses.
Commands executed on node3 (z):
Similar to node2, attempted connections to node1 (x) and node2 (y) using their respective machine IP addresses and virtual IPs. However, I encountered 'Connection refused' errors when attempting to connect to node1 (x) using machine IP addresses and virtual IP, and while connecting to node2 (y) using its machine IP.
Despite verifying the virtual binding and ruling out firewall issues, I remain puzzled by this behavior and seek suggestions for further debugging.
